# Routing in CodeIgniter for (:any)

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I'm trying to make my CodeIgniter application work similarly to WordPress.

I want to be able to make these kind of URLs:

http://www.example.com/my-post-example

http://www.example.com/new-headline-here

http://www.example.com/i-love-stackoverflow

My routing:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "core/index/$1";
```

Which will call my Core controller and pass the page name into the index function.

I then lookup in my database for the page name and display the page to the user. So far so good.

However, there will be times when I want to call another controller. For example:

http://www.example.com/admin/edit_page/3

http://www.example.com/admin/settings

Now I assume my route will just grab all these rules and send them into my Core controller. Is there a way to make an exception for certain pages? Or is it a good idea to do this check inside my Core controller.

For example,

```
if ($page not in DB) {
   // Call controller/method
}
```

This seems a little redundant since I just want CodeIgniter to handle this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The routing rule you using it is OK for your purpose.

If you use `http://www.example.com/admin/edit_page/3` this link it will send you `admin` controller and `edit_page` method.It will not use routes `any` rule.

However you will get one problem if your link looks like this

```
http://www.example.com/my-post-example/test
```

It will try to go `my-post-example` controller and test method.

Again `http://www.example.com/admin` will use routes `any` rule, means it will redirect your to core controller instead of `admin/index`. In that case your url should be `http://www.example.com/admin/index`

**Finally** If you call your other link with controller/method name it will be OK using your `any` rule

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to match any URL pattern? Including with /? So admin/edit/lol/ would go to core/index too? Or would I have to add (:any)/(:any)/(:any) all the time?

Comment: add another rule before your `$route['(:any)'] = "core/index/$1";`rule `$route['admin/edit/lol'] = "core/index";`

Comment: What if I want to route any data to the function, like: admin/edit/lol => core/index and also admin/new/test => core/index. Is there a better way than adding each individual rule? Like route['admin/(:any)/(:any)'] - but with the potential to add a 3rd, 4th and 5th up to infinite.

Comment: Yes you can write as many rule as you want. But you have to maintain ordering. And you can optimize code by writing one rule for similar type of rules.